# How to bind routines as opening the garage door to google maps?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

Is it possible configuring Google Assistant so that it automatically starts the "open the garage door" routine when Google Maps detects I am home? For instance after navigating me home Google Maps shows me a welcome message as soon as I reach my destination. At this point I'd like it to automatically trigger the action to open my garage door. Does anybody know if it's possible and how we get that working?

Comment: can google assistant open the garage door now?

Comment: yes, it can. I have already a voice command that starts this routine. I'd like it to start automatically tough, with no need to give any other voice command.

Comment: Google Maps will take a few minutes to work out that you are home.  You will probably be indoors with a cup of tea before it catches up.  Better to use a trigger like connecting to your home wifi - if that reaches to your garage.

Comment: I am not totally comfortable with my garage door opening every time I connect my home WiFi but I think somehow I can work on this idea. Thanks @Chenmunka

Comment: IFTTT + some kind of BLE beacon and a related app on your phone?

Comment: I'll have a look on your suggestion. Thanks @jcaron

Comment: @jcaron had it nailed.

Answer (score 1):

The latest comment from Google<sup>*</sup> I can find is [this](https://support.google.com/assistant/thread/465842?hl=en) which says no.

The only trigger location based trigger appears to be reminders.

<sup>*</sup> At least on their support forum

Comment: That's sad news for sure. I need to figure out something else then. Thanks - also for the link

Comment: send a voice command from your vehicle

Comment: If you have Android Auto that will work, I regularly turn lights off as I leave home from the  car

Comment: I really have issues with the voice commands when I need it. That's why I was wondering about a solution based on another trigger such as this welcome message or even using coordinates. But thanks anyway ;)